# how does def change a python function

Tags: python, function, class

I am trying some of the practice problems on `leetcode` and I am running into an issue on the `fizzbuzz` problem.

As far as I can tell my `code` works correctly when I `run` it separately in my own `python` editor **(pycharm)** .

But when I add back in the `class` and `def` lines running the `code` just comes back with process finished with `exit` code 0.

```
class Solution(object):
    def fizzBuzz(self, n):

        ans = []
        for i in range(1, 6):
            if (i % 3 == 0) and (i%5 != 0):
                ans.append("fizz")
            if (i% 3 != 0) and (i%5 == 0):
                ans.append("buzz")
            if (i % 3 != 0) and (i % 5 != 0):
                ans.append(str(i))
```

When I `run` this on the websites check answer thing only get back `['1']` but if I take out the `class` and `def` lines it `runs` as I expected it to.

Whether `def` and `class` do something here that changes how the program runs?

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: If you define a function with `def`, you need to call it somewhere in your program, otherwise the code inside the function will not be run. Also, if the function is a class method, you will have to create a class object and call its member function after that.

Comment: I was assuming that in this the run code button calls the class and function itself. As far as I can tell it does run the code and call the function since when I give it custom input of 5 so its not just testing 1 I only get back 1. 

I edited the code portion to take out a bunch of extra fluff that I had in there for debugging purposes.

@thomas kuhn it might be a duplicate, im not sure if the issue im having is because there is something wrong with my code of if im assuming too much automation in leetcode's "run code" button.

Comment: @Taylor.C, if you add `class` and `def` the output is `[1]`?

Comment: if I add the class and def lines in pycharm it just exits with a code of 0 which makes sense since im running a object with no call.

when I run it without the def and class lines, so just testing the code inside I get the right output but with the def and class lines added back in I only get 1 when submitting to leetcode, so im unsure if im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this code how in example!

```
class Solution(object):
    def fizzBuzz(self, n):

        ans = []
        for i in range(1, 6):

            # app = False
            print(i)
            if (i % 3 == 0) and (i%5 != 0):
                ans.append("fizz")
                print("appended fizz")
             #  app = True
            if (i% 3 != 0) and (i%5 == 0):
                ans.append("buzz")
                print("appended buzz")
             #   app = True
            if (i % 3 != 0) and (i % 5 != 0):
                ans.append(str(i))
                print("appended i")
            app = False
        print("final answer")
        print(ans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = Solution()
    n = input('Please, input n: ')
    solution.fizzBuzz(n)
```

Comment: That works for running it myself which does solve half of my problem. I guess my main issue is that I dont understand how much leetcode automates checking code when you submit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

def is used to create a function, you need to call functions in order to execute them

Answer (score 0):

```
#Seems like you are new to Object oriented programming in python,
#keyword def is used to define a method and key word class for 
#defining a class. Since you have defined fizzbuzz inside the class
#Solution, you need to create an object for that class to access its members
class Solution(object):
    def fizzBuzz(self, n):

        ans = []
        for i in range(1, 6):
            if (i % 3 == 0) and (i%5 != 0):
                ans.append("fizz")
            if (i% 3 != 0) and (i%5 == 0):
                ans.append("buzz")
            if (i % 3 != 0) and (i % 5 != 0):
                ans.append(str(i))

solutionObj = Solution()
solutionObj.fizzBuzz(<your input>)
```